# Maven dependency management not being considered

Tags: java, maven

I'm working on some legacy software which has 5 modules. Somewhere in this project something is pulling in `spring-web 3.2.1.RELEASE` despite the fact I have explicitly stated that I want `spring-web 5.1.9.RELEASE`.

I have placed the following in each modules POM file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

In the parent POM from which they all inherit I have placed:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Based on this [article](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/maven/use-maven-dependency-management-2/) I have satisfied both dependency mediation and dependency management. Despite this when I run my code `spring-web 3.2.1.RELEASE` is loaded and I get a `NoSuchMethodError`.

When I run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` and I search for `spring-web` I get 32 hits over many, many lines (so tree structure is irrelevant):

```
Search "spring-web" (32 hits in 1 file)
  new 3 (32 hits)
    Line 726: [INFO] \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
    Line 1371: [INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile
    Line 1651: [INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.3.3.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 1687: [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 5.1.9.RELEASE; omitted for conflict with 5.1.9.RELEASE)
    Line 1744: [INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.1.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 1850: [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.5.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 2464: [INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.1.3.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 3040: [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.1.3.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 3051: [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.3.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 3112: [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.2.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 3144: [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.1.3.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 3188: [INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.4.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 3189: [INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.4.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 3434: [INFO] |        +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.3.24.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 3539: [INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 5.1.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 3548: [INFO] \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
    Line 3688: [INFO]    |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.3.3.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 3725: [INFO]    |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.6.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 3761: [INFO]    |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 5.1.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 3776: [INFO]    |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.0.3.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 3824: [INFO]    |     +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.1.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 3931: [INFO]    |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.5.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 4544: [INFO]    |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.1.3.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 5105: [INFO]    |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.1.3.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 5116: [INFO]    |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.3.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 5177: [INFO]    |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.2.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 5209: [INFO]    |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.1.3.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 5253: [INFO]    |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.4.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 5254: [INFO]    |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.4.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 5499: [INFO]    |        +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.3.24.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 5604: [INFO]    |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 5.1.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
    Line 5613: [INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile
```

I don't really know what I'm looking at here but I guess my problem lies at the end of one of my modules:

```
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.3.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]       +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 5.1.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]       +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 5.1.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]       +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]       \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 5.1.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
```

This all leads up to:

```
[INFO] -----------------------< com.team.im:im-jws >------------------------
[INFO] Building IM Java Web Start 4.91.0-SNAPSHOT                         [4/6]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ im-jws ---
[INFO] com.team.im:im-jws:pom:4.91.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- com.team.im:im-jar:jar:4.91.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
```

which are two modules in the project.

I must be reading this incorrectly but this suggests that somewhere in the project the version has been explicitly declared as `3.2.1.RELEASE`. The parent POM itself defines a parent which is a corporate root POM which does indeed define `<spring.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>`.

How can I overwrite this and force it to use `5.1.9.RELEASE`?

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any additional dependencyManagement entries in one of the parent POMs? Maybe one that is using the `spring.version` property?

Comment: The parent POM outside the project does have dependencyManagement. Can this be overridden?

Comment: Does it use `spring.version`? Maybe the easiest approach is to just set `spring.version` to the value you want (in your own parent POM).

Comment: I have set it to the value I want and it is still loading it from an earlier version.

Comment: Then I would check if there is some other dependencyManagement entry for your dependency in one of the parent POMs.

Comment: Do you mean outside of the project? What if there is? I'm unable to modify the POMs outside the project.

Comment: Actually, I am a bit confused as well. I thought that your direct dependency in the module should override _everything_, except for explicit dependencies that are inherited. For dependencyManagement I am not sure if parent overwrites child or vice versa. Does a parent outside your project define dependencies (I mean not only dependencyManagement but actual dependencies?)